# How to create CAN frame using SocketCAN interface in C using values larger and smaller than 8 bit

Tags: c, can-bus

I need to write three different CAN messages to a CAN bus.
The first message consists of 8 values of 8 bits so no problem there but the second and third message are more irregular
In the third message I have three values all with a size of 16bits and the third message has some values which are smaller than 8 bits.
How can I properly create the data for the CAN frame using values larger or smaller than 8 bits.

This is my code

`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int s; 
    struct sockaddr_can addr;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct can_frame frame;
    struct can_frame frame2;

    if ((s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW)) < 0) {
        perror("Socket");
        return 1;
    }

    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "vcan0" );
    ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
    addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;

    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Bind");
        return 1;
    }

    frame.can_id = 0x500;
    frame.can_dlc = 8;
    frame.data[0] = 122;
    frame.data[1] = 150;
    frame.data[2] = -27;
    frame.data[3] = -22;
    frame.data[4] = 160;
    frame.data[5] = 160;
    frame.data[6] = -60;
    frame.data[7] = 90;

    frame2.can_id = 0x501;
    frame.can_dlc = 6;
    frame.data[0] = 32766;
    frame.data[2] = -32765;
    frame.data[4] = 20542;

    if (write(s, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame)) != sizeof(struct can_frame)) {
        perror("Write");
        return 1;
    }

    if (close(s) < 0) {
        perror("Close");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`
Index 0 obviously corresponds to the first 8 bits of the data frame but I don't really know any other way to do this because I have very little experience with C

I would like to be able to make these CAN frames properly with the data on two indexes but have no clue how to do this.
Aswell as a way to use single bits instead of 8 bits using the index of the frame.data object since I need to make a CAN message where multiple values exist in the single 8 bit data frame of the can message. If that makes sense

Comment: `frame.data[0] = 32766`. Data here would be a 8 bit value. You need to specify both the bytes as `frame.data[0] = 32766 & 0xFF` and `frame.data[1] = 32766 >> 8`

Comment: @RishikeshRaje I wouldn't make any assumptions of the format of the CAN protocol used, since it isn't mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you *cannot do this unless you know the network endianess* of the specific CAN bus. Big endian is the most common, but some CAN application layers like CANopen use little endian for the payload.

Assuming network = big endian, assuming `32766`, `-32765` and `20542` are your 16 bit numbers, then:

```c
const int16_t data16[3] = { 32766, -32765, 20542 };
...
frame.data[0] = ((uint16_t)data16[0] >> 8) & 0xFFu;
frame.data[1] = ((uint16_t)data16[0] >> 0) & 0xFFu;
frame.data[2] = ((uint16_t)data16[1] >> 8) & 0xFFu;
frame.data[3] = ((uint16_t)data16[1] >> 0) & 0xFFu;
frame.data[4] = ((uint16_t)data16[2] >> 8) & 0xFFu;
frame.data[5] = ((uint16_t)data16[2] >> 0) & 0xFFu;
```

Or if you will:

```c
for(size_t i=0; i<3; i++)
{
  frame.data[i*2]   = ((uint16_t)data16[i] >> 8) & 0xFFu;
  frame.data[i*2+1] = ((uint16_t)data16[i] >> 0) & 0xFFu;
}
```

Here the bit shifts are the same no matter if CPU is big/little endian, but you have to swap MS and LS bytes in case the network uses little endian.

Comment: Thank you that helps immensely! The protocol of the CAN bus is little endian in this case though